# docker registry push failed on localhost

Tags: docker, push, docker-registry

I'm running docker registry on my localhost:5000, when i try to put the image getting the below error.

```
bash-4.2# docker push localhost:5000/test5
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/test5] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Put http://localhost:5000/v1/repositories/test5/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: 
connection refused
```

below is the entry on /etc/default/docker

bash-4.2# more /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry localhost:5000"

Can someone help here ?

Comment: Have you checked here? https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploying-a-plain-http-registry and restarted docker after the changes?

Comment: Can you provide the commands used to run your registry and it's configuration?